# How to use Express JS 4.0's csurf?

Tags: javascript, express, csrf, csrf-protection

I have been checking [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf)'s wiki, but it is empty. This module adds a `csrfToken()` function to user requests, but then, how should I use it?

Can someone give a code example with explanations? What should I do on user side? What should I do on server-side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `csurf` middleware is designed to reject requests that contain a payload (body parameters, for example) if it doesn't have a valid token.  Here's how you would use it:

```
app.use(require('body-parser')());
app.use(require('cookie-parser')('YOUR SECRET GOES HERE'));
app.use(require('express-session')());

app.use(require('csurf')());

app.get('/some-form', function(req, res){
    res.send('<form action="/process" method="POST">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="' + req.csrfToken() + '">' +
        'Favorite color: <input type="text" name="favoriteColor">' +
        '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
        '</form>');
});

app.post('/process', function(req, res){
    res.send('<p>Your favorite color is "' + req.body.favoriteColor + '".');
});
```

Try taking out the `req.csrfToken()` (or replacing it with something else); you will find that the form no longer works.

Note that you need sessions for `csurf` to work.  If you want understand the reasons you would use `csurf`, see the Wikipedia article on [cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: in app.post i have to check csrfToken or not?

Comment: No, Paresh, the csurf middleware handles that for you.  If the `_csrf` field isn't present and correct, it will be rejected before your +post+ handler.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am return index.html from express.js with _csrf token in cookie and front side in angular i get cookie and set in with in form tag with _csrf and set token from cookie to hidden and now i press submit but token always return  EBADCSRFTOKEN. Where i am wrong please tell me.

Comment: I am checking in req.body csrf token is present and i am also check browser cookie value it is match with passed value but it still reject the request

Comment: I can't really tell from your description, Paresh. Maybe try asking a new question with your application file and form source?

Comment: I am just host the site https://tranquil-earth-4097.herokuapp.com/login. here you can see in inspect element > resource > cookie here cookie is stored successfully. now i am post my code of index.js. Please see thise bin http://pastebin.com/Uvkj4ZH4. Thanks for helping me. @Ethan Brown